# simple_html_dom find links on page and scrape details from each

Tags: php, html, dom, scrape

I have one page with several links, each link lead to new page with details in table. I want to store all links from original page and scrape table data from each link (page).
So:

```
OriginalPage -|- Link1 -> TableData
              |- Link2 -> TableData
              |- Link3 -> TableData
```

I success extract links from original page, and table data from one link, but I don't know how to make loop to extract data from all links at once.
All link have a simple pattern, and all pages have same table (but different data).
This is what I have:

```
    $city1 = file_get_html('http://www.xxxx.xx/sl/cities/city1');
    // Get links from page that contain word "info" and extract date from URL (date is important)
//Example link on original page: http://www.xxxx.xx/sl/cities/info-onday-19-05-2017-d"
    foreach($city1->find('a[href]') as $link){
        if(strstr($link, 'info')){
            preg_match('#onday (.*?). #', $link, $match);
            $date = $match[1];
        }
    }
    //Get table data from one link
    $city1DetailsUrl = "http://www.xxxx.xx/sl/cities/info-onday-".$date."-d";

    $city1Details = file_get_html($city1DetailsUrl);
    $table = $city1Details->find('table', 0);
    $rowData = array();
    foreach($table->find('tr') as $row) {
        // initialize array to store the cell data from each row
        $info = array();
        foreach($row->find('td') as $cell) {
            // push the cell's text to the array
            $info[] = $cell->plaintext;
        }
        $rowData[] = $info;
    }
    foreach ($rowData as $row => $tr) {
        foreach ($tr as $td) {
            echo  $td .'<br>';
        } 
    }
```

Summary: find links on original page that contain some word (info), scrapte table data from each that link (page).